# What's the maximum number of read replicas you can create with the Database for MySQL service on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure

I can't find this anywhere in the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-read-replicas) and I don't want to incur costs to figure it out. How many read replica's can you create with the Database for MySQL service on Microsoft Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first paragraph, second sentence of the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-read-replicas) you so kindly linked to:

> ...
>   The read replica feature allows you to replicate data from an Azure Database for MySQL server to a read-only server. **You can replicate from the master server to up to five replicas.**

Comment: Thanks I guess I read it too quickly

Comment: That is a limit imposed by the service though, as far as I know there is effectively no limit to what number of replica's MySQL can theoretically support. Although the required [`server_id`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_id)  might provide a hard upper limit of 4294967295 replica's you'll likely run into other resource limits well before that.